# ReadBsonType can only be called when State is Type, not when State is Value

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I am trying to use a [BsonClassMap](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/) and when it runs I get the following error:

> ReadBsonType can only be called when State is Type, not when State is
>   Value

Comment: Seriously, though, this question doesn't look complete.  You may want to finish it.